# Cannot run integration test because of IllegalStateException in grails-3.0.1 plugin application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, integration-testing

Context: I've created a new Grails plugin named "samplePlugin". It has one domain class Person and an integration test PersonSpec. Now, when I run `grails test-app`, the test fails with below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [sampleplugin.Person] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.currentGormInstanceApi(GormEntity.groovy:52)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:165)
    at sampleplugin.PersonSpec.$tt__$spock_feature_0_1(PersonSpec.groovy:25)
    at sampleplugin.PersonSpec.test save_closure2(PersonSpec.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:67)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.executeAndRollback(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:64)
    at sampleplugin.PersonSpec.test save(PersonSpec.groovy)
```

class Person.groovy is:

```
package sampleplugin

class Person {
    String name
}
```

class PersonSpec.groovy is:

```
package sampleplugin

import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

  void "canary test"() {
      expect:
          true == true
  }

  void "test save"() {
    when:
      new Person(name: "John Doe").save flush:true
    then:
      1 == Person.count()
  }
}
```

Here is the GitHub link for the sample grails3 plugin https://github.com/puneetbehl/samplePlugin.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by adding `compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"` under dependencies in build.gradle. It seems like a Grails plugin application doesn't have it by default. Below is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.4.0.RELEASE"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.1"
}

version "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
group "org.grails.plugins"

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
// Used for publishing to central repository, remove if not needed
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/grailsCentralPublishing.gradle'
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    provided "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    provided "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

Comment: Needed to add also `compile(group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '4.3.10.Final')`